# Global class for all google ads in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables, google-mobile-ads

i want to write all google ads code in a single class to prevent code repetation in every class in flutter

i have try to implement App open ad in a seprate class and call it where i wanted to show. but i want to show all my ads on different screens with single ads containing class.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, I created an `enum` called `AdsType` and an abstract `Ads` class with the `showAds` method.
I use `switch-case` to display different types of ads based on `AdsType`.
This method can be called with different `AdsType` values to show the relevant ad.

Step 1 : write enum.

```
enum AdsType { googleAd, interstitialAd, rewardedAd, bannerAd }
```

Step 2 : write method with switch-case.

```
abstract class Ads {
  static void showAds({required AdsType adsType}) {
    switch (adsType) {
      case AdsType.googleAd:
        {
          // TODO: write code here for googleAd
        }
        break;
      case AdsType.interstitialAd:
        {
          // TODO: write code here for interstitialAd
        }
        break;
      case AdsType.rewardedAd:
        {
          // TODO: write code here for rewardedAd
        }
        break;
      case AdsType.bannerAd:
        {
          // TODO: write code here for bannerAd
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Step 3 : Using method like below:

```
  //  call bannerAd
  Ads.showAds(adsType: AdsType.bannerAd);

  //  call interstitialAd
  Ads.showAds(adsType: AdsType.interstitialAd);

  //  call rewardedAd
  Ads.showAds(adsType: AdsType.rewardedAd);

  //  call bannerAd
  Ads.showAds(adsType: AdsType.bannerAd);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this  [repo](https://github.com/bigbott/my_google_ads_example). It contains exactly what asked for.

*ad_helper.dart*
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

final adHelper = AdHelper._();

class AdHelper {
  AdHelper._();

  final AdRequest request = const AdRequest(
    keywords: <String>['foo', 'bar'],
    contentUrl: 'http://example.com/bar.html',
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
  );

  RewardedAd? _rewardedAd;
  int _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;
  RewardedInterstitialAd? _rewardedInterstitialAd;
  int _numRewardedInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
  int _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
  int maxFailedLoadAttempts = 3;

  init() {
    initGoogleMobileAds();
    createRewardedAd();
    createRewardedInterstitialAd();
    createInterstitialAd();
  }

  Future<InitializationStatus> initGoogleMobileAds() {
    return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }

  void createRewardedAd() {
    RewardedAd.load(
        adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
            ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917'
            : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313',
        request: request,
        rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) {
            print('$ad loaded.');
            _rewardedAd = ad;
            _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            print('RewardedAd failed to load: $error');
            _rewardedAd = null;
            _numRewardedLoadAttempts += 1;
            if (_numRewardedLoadAttempts < maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
              createRewardedAd();
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void showRewardedAd() {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show rewarded before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _rewardedAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
          print('ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
        createRewardedAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        createRewardedAd();
      },
    );

    _rewardedAd!.setImmersiveMode(true);
    _rewardedAd!.show(
        onUserEarnedReward: (AdWithoutView ad, RewardItem reward) {
      print('$ad with reward $RewardItem(${reward.amount}, ${reward.type})');
    });
    _rewardedAd = null;
  }

  void createRewardedInterstitialAd() {
    RewardedInterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
            ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379'
            : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866',
        request: request,
        rewardedInterstitialAdLoadCallback: RewardedInterstitialAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (RewardedInterstitialAd ad) {
            print('$ad loaded.');
            _rewardedInterstitialAd = ad;
            _numRewardedInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            print('RewardedInterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
            _rewardedInterstitialAd = null;
            _numRewardedInterstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
            if (_numRewardedInterstitialLoadAttempts < maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
              createRewardedInterstitialAd();
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void showRewardedInterstitialAd() {
    if (_rewardedInterstitialAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show rewarded interstitial before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _rewardedInterstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback =
        FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedInterstitialAd ad) =>
          print('$ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedInterstitialAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
        createRewardedInterstitialAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent:
          (RewardedInterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        createRewardedInterstitialAd();
      },
    );

    _rewardedInterstitialAd!.setImmersiveMode(true);
    _rewardedInterstitialAd!.show(
        onUserEarnedReward: (AdWithoutView ad, RewardItem reward) {
      print('$ad with reward $RewardItem(${reward.amount}, ${reward.type})');
    });
    _rewardedInterstitialAd = null;
  }

  void createInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
            ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712'
            : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910',
        request: request,
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
            print('$ad loaded');
            _interstitialAd = ad;
            _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
            _interstitialAd!.setImmersiveMode(true);
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error.');
            _numInterstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
            _interstitialAd = null;
            if (_numInterstitialLoadAttempts < maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
              createInterstitialAd();
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void showInterstitialAd() {
    if (_interstitialAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show interstitial before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) =>
          print('ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
        createInterstitialAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        createInterstitialAd();
      },
    );
    _interstitialAd!.show();
    _interstitialAd = null;
  }
}
```

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_google_ads_example/ad_helper.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  adHelper.init();
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      adHelper.showRewardedAd();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Show rewarded ad')),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50,),
                     OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      adHelper.showRewardedInterstitialAd();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Show rewarded interstitial ad')),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50,),
                     OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      adHelper.showInterstitialAd();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Show interstitial ad')),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```